# prablem django install and cmd?

Tags: python-3.x, django, windows, cmd

### I entered the following code in cmd and line 5 has an error
I also tried these codes but did not get the desired result
(py -m venv env)
please help me!!!

```
C:\Users\baran>python  
C:\Users\baran>pip  
C:\Users\baran>pip install virtualenv   
C:\Users\baran>pip install virtualenvwrapper 
E:\learning\project\django pro\toplrean>virtualenv -p python env 
'virtualenv' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: try `python -m virtualenv env`

Comment: It worked, but not the result I wanted
A file was created with your code, but a small number of files were created in the script folder (8 files). I entered the above code for my friend and a large number of files (54) were created.
Is there a special reason ???

Answer (score 0):

As per the title, your goal is to start an existing django project. I suggest you use venv which is part of the standard python distribution. In powershell and from your project folder:

```
python -m venv ./env
./env/scripts/activate
```

From there, you should be at the same point as described in your original post. I would then expect the following commands to be entered to have your project working:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Not knowing the details of your project you might have to adapt to your reallity.